# Python 2.7 Can't Enumerate with index value from MySQL database using pymysql

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pymysql, enumerate

I'm selecting a value from a MySQL table, and using this value as part of a statement to INSERT records.

I want to use the enumerate() function, starting with an index of the value selected from the db, but I can't get it to work. I think I need to convert a tuple to a string or integer - or find a better way of doing it.

```
My code:

# list declaration
dbList = []
apList = []
currentID = []

# Get highest apID value from db    
def getAPCount():
    cur.execute("SELECT MAX(apID) FROM AP;")
    row = cur.fetchall()
    currentID.append(row[0])

# Compare lists and add new APs to the db
def updateAPs():

    cID = currentID[0]
    for index, ap in enumerate(apList, cID):
        if ap in dbList:
            continue
        else:
            newAPs = kr.device_by_mac(ap, fields=fields)
            for newAP in newAPs:

                count = index + 1
```

Gives me this error:

```
for index, ap in enumerate(apList, str(cID)):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

My question is:

How can I convert the value to string so enumerate works? OR - is there a better way to do this? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What do you get from `type(cID)`?

Comment: @KevinBott Sorry I didn't write it's a tuple in the post, so output is:
<type 'tuple'>